# ereg_replace, preg_replace and PHP 5.3.0

Tags: php, ereg-replace

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Changing ereg_replace to equivalent preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269693/changing-ereg-replace-to-equivalent-preg-replace)
>   [Converting ereg expressions to preg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/converting-ereg-expressions-to-preg)

Can anyone show me the equivalent of :

```
ereg_replace("\n#[^\n]*\n", "\n", $sql)
```

in preg_replace

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

All you need in this case is [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) (here `/`):

```
preg_replace("/\n#[^\n]*\n/", "\n", $sql)
```

Also read about the [difference of PCRE from POSIX](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.posix).

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace("~\n#[^\n]*\n~", "\n", $sql);
```