# Changing ereg_replace to equivalent preg_replace

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270004/how-can-i-convert-ereg-expressions-to-preg-in-php)

What is the equivalent using preg_replace to the following expression?

```
ereg_replace('^' . $g_lang_prefix, '', $t_var );
```

Comment: Most important difference: PCRE need [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/^' . preg_quote($g_lang_prefix,'/') . '/', '', $t_var );
```

If you need `$g_lang_prefix` working as a common regex then omit `preg_quote`

```
preg_replace('/^' . $g_lang_prefix . '/', '', $t_var );
```

(quite obvious)

Also if you need this second solution, but your `$g_lang` can contain even this char `/` then you need to escape at least it:

```
preg_replace('/^' . str_replace('/','\/',$g_lang_prefix) . '/', '', $t_var );
```

Comment: +1 for using preg_quote.

Comment: I had to, consdering I didn't know what `$g_lang_prefix` could be :)

Comment: Maybe `$g_lang_prefix` is supposed to contain a regex for the prefix.

Comment: @yes Thanks, this `preg_replace('/^' . preg_quote($g_lang_prefix,'/') . '/', '', $t_var );` worked very well!

Comment: @salathe: can you explain why that -1 ?